# In modaI I have goback button which is currently needs to be clicked twice. I want to close the modal on single click of goback button in react native

Tags: react-native

In modaI I have goback button which is currently needs to be clicked twice. I want to close the modal on single click of goback button in react native.

<Modal animationType='fade' visible={isVisitedByModal} onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ isVisitedByModal: false })}>

```
onModalBackPressed = () => {
    this.setState({ isVisitedByModal: false })
};
```

Below is my modal component
<Modal animationType='fade' visible={isVisitedByModal} onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ isVisitedByModal: false })}>


<Searchbar placeholder={`Search people`} ref={ref => this.textInput = ref} icon='magnify' inputStyle={GlobalStyle.searchbarInput} style={{ ...GlobalStyle.searchbarStyle, marginHorizontal: 20, marginTop: 20 }} iconColor={Colors.TaupeGray} onChangeText={(text) => this.onFilteredData(text)} value={searchText} />
<FlatList
data={allUsers}
renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderContacts(item, index)}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
/>

Comment: Could you update the question and provide the whole component? Currently its hard to tell where the problem is

Comment: Question updated. Pls check